database.db file being created in the wrong directory
My project structure is:
studybudy
│   main.py
│
└── notecard
    │   __init__.py
    │   main.py
    │   views.py
    │   auth.py
    │
    ├── static
    │   └── (static files)
    │
    ├── templates
    │   └── (HTML templates)
    │
    └── database.db

python main.py 
creates an 'instance' folder in the root directory and the database.db file is created inside of that. The 'pycache' folder is successfully created inside of 'notecard'. Why is the database.db file created in the root directory and not inside 'notecard'?
Here is my init.py file
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from os import path

    db = SQLAlchemy()
    DB_NAME = 'database.db'

    def create_app():
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'notecard'
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =                            
        f"sqlite:///{DB_NAME}"
        db.init_app(app)
    
    
        from .views import views
        from .auth import auth

        app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
        app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

        from .models import User, Note

        with app.app_context():
            db.create_all()

        return app

    def create_database(app):
        if not path.exists('notecard/' + DB_NAME):
            db.create_all(app=app)
            print('Created Database!')

and here is my main.py file
    from notecard import create_app

    app = create_app()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)

I tried using os.path.dirname and os.path.join to ensure the file was created inside of the correct subdirectory.
    app.instance_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'notecard')    
    db_path = os.path.join(app.instance_path, DB_NAME)
    print(db_path)

The code above printed
studybudy/notecard/database.db

Does this mean that it's attempting to create database.db inside of a folder database.db or is this showing me where the file would be created if successful?
When adjusting
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =    f"sqlite:///{DB_NAME}"
to
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =  f"sqlite:///{db_path}"
The switch above gives me an error message saying SQLAlchemy encountered a problem when trying to connect to the SQLite database file specified in the URI.

"The code above printed" What? Nothing?

Sorry, my first post and I am still editing it so it is actually readable. The code printed:
studybudy/notecard/database.db

Since you're using a relative path, the database file will be created in whatever your programs current working directory is.
